# Linux Mint and wired connection problem

Tags: networking, ethernet

I've recently installed Linux Mint 18.1 and I'm very new to it.
Everything is fine with wifi, but I cannot access the internet via ethernet cable. When I try to connect, Chromium just says that there is no internet connection.

Output of `sudo ifconfig -a`:

```
enp5s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 1c:75:08:26:90:db  
      inet addr:192.168.0.100  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::1e75:8ff:fe26:90db/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:7381 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:7203 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:1278143 (1.2 MB)  TX bytes:789190 (789.1 KB)
      Interrupt:18 
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:98 (98.0 B)  TX bytes:98 (98.0 B)
wlp4s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:26:c6:da:7e:30  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

output of `iwconfig`:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp5s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp4s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

Relevant output of `lspci`:

```
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5764M Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 10)
```

I tried adding the following lines to `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto enp5s0
iface enp5s0 inet dhcp
```

but it doesn't work. I still can't connect to the internet.

Output of `dmesg | tail -n 20` after plugging in the network cable:

```
[   41.903417] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEGP.VGA_._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[   41.903485] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEGP.VGA_._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[   41.903552] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEGP.VGA_._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[   41.904761] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEGP.VGA_._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[   42.023873] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to enable radio.
[   42.025694] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   42.033148] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   42.033265] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
[   43.350521] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   43.354652] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   43.354750] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
[   43.395109] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp4s0: link is not ready
[   43.489583] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp4s0: link is not ready
[ 2299.040250] CE: hpet increased min_delta_ns to 20115 nsec
[ 4705.704005] tg3 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: Link is down
[ 4713.523072] tg3 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex
[ 4713.523093] tg3 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: Flow control is off for TX and off for RX
[ 4779.820050] tg3 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: Link is down
[ 4786.441835] tg3 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex
[ 4786.441856] tg3 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: Flow control is off for TX and off for RX
```

output of `ping -c2 8.8.8.8`

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1007ms
```

**EDIT**

output of `sudo iptables -vL`

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

**ONE MORE EDIT**

output from `ipconfig` on Windows (it's russian language, sorry)

```
Настройка протокола IP для Windows

Адаптер PPP Internet:

   DNS-суффикс подключения . . . . . :
   IPv4-адрес. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.57.121
   Маска подсети . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Основной шлюз. . . . . . . . . : 0.0.0.0

Ethernet adapter Tunngle:

   Состояние среды. . . . . . . . : Среда передачи недоступна.
   DNS-суффикс подключения . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter Подключение по локальной сети 2:

   DNS-суффикс подключения . . . . . :
   Локальный IPv6-адрес канала . . . : fe80::d5fe:d1a2:2e54:eeeb%16
   Автонастройка IPv4-адреса . . . . : 169.254.238.235
   Маска подсети . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Основной шлюз. . . . . . . . . :

Адаптер беспроводной локальной сети Беспроводное сетевое соединение 2:

   Состояние среды. . . . . . . . : Среда передачи недоступна.
   DNS-суффикс подключения . . . . . :

Туннельный адаптер isatap.{7B8FAF91-9786-4E2C-A66F-3387471FD72B}:

   Состояние среды. . . . . . . . : Среда передачи недоступна.
   DNS-суффикс подключения . . . . . :

Туннельный адаптер isatap.{FD3701FE-07FF-4726-ACD9-38B926C34CF5}:

   Состояние среды. . . . . . . . : Среда передачи недоступна.
   DNS-суффикс подключения . . . . . :
```

Comment: Do you have a default route (`ip route ls | grep default`)? If so, can you ping the "via" IP address?

Comment: @derobert default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp5s0

Comment: @derobert `--- 192.168.0.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1008ms`
it's network of my home

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have any firewall rules on this machine that could be blocking the connection? E.g., `iptables -vL` to check for firewall rules. Also, are there any other wired machines on the network? Do they work?

Comment: @derobert `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'ip_tables': Operation not permitted
iptables v1.6.0: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.`

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned: `iptables -vL` needs to be run as root (I'm guessing that's what the error means). Also, did you see the edited comment—are there other wired devices on this network, and if so do they work?

Comment: @derobert no there are no other wired devices, but when I switch to Windows and connect ethernet cable then everything works fine

Comment: Odd. Unless there are firewall rules, I'm really scratching my head on why that'd be. Does Windows get the same IP address and gateway? (`ipconfig` in the command prompt on Windows to check, I believe). I'm going to guess it does get the same ones, which leaves me scratching my head as it *should* be working. Especially since DHCP worked.

Comment: @derobert added firewall rules in new edit to question

Comment: @derobert ok I'll swith to Windows and run `ipconfig`, then I'll write comment with output from it

Comment: @derobert added `ipconfug` output from Windows

Comment: @derobert seems like ip for Windows is 192.168.57.121, when for Linux it's 192.168.0.100

Comment: Aha! That says 'PPP' in it, which makes me thing you're connecting straight to a DSL modem (not router) which is using PPPoE... If that's correct, you need to set up PPPoE on Linux. There is a pppoeconf program that'll do it for you (definitely needs to be run as root).

Comment: @derobert yes, right, I am connecting to modem, when I connect to router via ethernet cable everything is ok, sorry I should said it earlier I really apologise

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely it then—if you want to connect directly to the modem, you need to configure PPPoE. You'll probably be prompted for your username & password assigned by your ISP. Other than that, `pppoeconf` should figure out everything.

Comment: @derobert thank you a lot man for figuring it out and for spending so many time here, have a nice day(I guess it's day in USA) ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out you need to run PPPoE to connect to the Internet. The easiest way to do that is to run `pppoeconf` and follow the prompts.

If instead you want to instead configure it by hand, it'd be something like this (taken from a working config I have):

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
auto enp5s0-ppp
iface enp5s0-ppp inet ppp
        pre-up ip link set enp5s0 up mtu 1508 # if your ISP supports
        provider your-isp
```

**/etc/ppp/pap-secrets**

Obviously, use your actual ISP-provided username and password instead of the placeholders here. The `*` specifies which remote this applies to, easiest to use `*` if you've only got one remote.

```
"your-username" * "your-password"
```

**/etc/ppp/peers/your-isp**

Note this one is a little different than my file—my config has static IP addresses, so there is a `local-ip:` line instead of `noipdefault`.

```
noipdefault
noauth
persist
maxfail 0

mtu 1500
mru 1500

noktune
defaultroute

ifname enp5s0-ppp

noaccomp 
default-asyncmap

plugin rp-pppoe.so enp5s0
user "your-username"
```